# Creating registered user homepage upon registration

Tags: nodes

If one were creating a growing directory on users say for example a 'staff directory' and one needed to allow each user there own editable homepage (ie manage their home page themselves using a wsyiwyg), in your opinion (assuming we don't use Panels/Views OR we DO use a Panels/Rules/Views (P/R/V) combination) what would be the best approach. Usages are unlimited but for example here: an HE university needs each lecturer to have their own home page which they our course can edit as need be (i.e. domain.ac/johndoe). This could allow users to create/edit their own frontend ala Myspace/Facebook style. I would rather use P/R/V combi if that is the most appropriate option rather than an 'off the shelf' Drupal module (but do point me to one if one exists that I have missed!). Flexibility & futureproof is key.

Comment: I now have come to think that this is acheiveable with the "Pathauto" module  as this turn Nodes and tokens in to URLs, so I will follow this route unless someone provides comments otherwise.